# MySQL - Update table with row number per group

Tags: mysql, sql

**Sample Data**

```
id  |  order_id  |  instalment_num  | date_due
---------------------------------------------------------
1   |  10000     |  1               | 2010-07-09 00:00:00
2   |  10000     |  1               | 2010-09-06 11:39:56
3   |  10001     |  1               | 2014-04-25 15:46:52
4   |  10002     |  1               | 2010-01-11 00:00:00
5   |  10003     |  1               | 2010-01-04 00:00:00
6   |  10003     |  1               | 2016-05-31 00:00:00
7   |  10003     |  1               | 2010-01-08 00:00:00
8   |  10003     |  1               | 2010-01-06 09:06:26
9   |  10004     |  1               | 2010-01-11 11:25:07
10  |  10004     |  1               | 2010-01-12 07:06:42
```

**Desired Result**

```
id  |  order_id  |  instalment_num  | date_due
---------------------------------------------------------
1   |  10000     |  1               | 2010-07-09 00:00:00
2   |  10000     |  2               | 2010-09-06 11:39:56
3   |  10001     |  1               | 2014-04-25 15:46:52
4   |  10002     |  1               | 2010-01-11 00:00:00
5   |  10003     |  1               | 2010-01-04 00:00:00
8   |  10003     |  2               | 2010-01-06 09:06:26
7   |  10003     |  3               | 2010-01-08 00:00:00
6   |  10003     |  4               | 2016-05-31 00:00:00
9   |  10004     |  1               | 2010-01-11 11:25:07
10  |  10004     |  2               | 2010-01-12 07:06:42
```

As you can see, I have an `instalment_num` column which should show the number/index of each row belonging to the `order_id`, determined by the `date_due ASC, id ASC` order.

How can I update the `instalment_num` column like this?

**Additional Notes**

- The `date_due` column is not unique, and there may be many `id`s or `order_id`s with the exact same timestamp.
- If the timestamp is the same for two rows belonging to the same `order_id`, it should order them by `id` as a fallback.
- I require a query which will update this column.

Comment: what you have try?

Comment: Can there be any duplicate order_id/date_due combos?

Comment: @jarlh Yes, and then it should be `date_due ASC, id ASC` order.

Comment: @HamzaZafeer Nothing, at the moment I know I don't know how to do it correctly until I learn a technique to do it.

Comment: I meant same date_due with same id twice.

Comment: @jarlh Yes it's possible. The date is selected by user-entry, so they can save the exact same date for different rows if they want.

Comment: It might be worth noting that, on recent versions of MySQL using the myisam engine, its possible to generate these numbers directly by specifying the autoincrement column as a secondary value in the primary key (although if the documentation is correct, this will break master-master asynch replication). http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is how I would do it:

```
SELECT a.id,
    a.order_id,
    COUNT(b.id)+1 AS instalment_num,
    a.date_due
FROM sample_data a
    LEFT JOIN sample_data b ON a.order_id=b.order_id AND (a.date_due>b.date_due OR (a.date_due=b.date_due AND a.id>b.id))
GROUP BY a.id, a.order_id, a.date_due
ORDER BY a.order_id, a.date_due, a.id
```

UPDATE version attempt:

```
UPDATE sample_data
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT a.id,
    COUNT(b.id)+1 AS instalment_num
FROM sample_data a
    JOIN sample_data b ON a.order_id=b.order_id AND (a.date_due>b.date_due OR (a.date_due=b.date_due AND a.id>b.id))
GROUP BY a.id) c ON c.id=sample_data.id
SET sample_data.instalment_num=c.instalment_num
```

Comment: Not fast, but it works. How do I turn this into an UPDATE instead?

Comment: I agree. It is not the fastest way of doing it but it is pretty clean and easy to understand. Working on the update... give me a minute...

Comment: I tried but getting `You can't specify target table for update in FROM clause` error. +1 for easy to understand.

Comment: I added it t my solution but I don't have an environment to test it so it may need tweaking.

Comment: The UPDATE version is good, except that the first instalment is numbered 0 instead of 1. So it goes 0, 2, 3...

Comment: I suspect COUNT returns NULL and not zero. In SQL server it would probably need something like `ISNULL(COUNT(b.id),0)+1` but I ma not sure if MySQL has that function or something else equivalent and unfortunately I don't have time to look into it at the moment.

Comment: No problem, I can use `IF()` probably.

Answer (score 3):

For the numbering to begin with 1:

```
UPDATE sample_data
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT a.id,
    COUNT(b.id) AS instalment_num
FROM sample_data a
    JOIN sample_data b ON a.order_id = b.order_id AND (a.date_due > b.date_due OR (a.date_due=b.date_due AND a.id + 1 > b.id))
GROUP BY a.id) c ON c.id = sample_data.id
SET sample_data.instalment_num = c.instalment_num
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to achieve what `ROW_NUMBER` with a partition would do using something like SQL Server or Oracle.  You can simulate this with an approriate query:

```
SELECT t.id, t.order_id,
(
    SELECT 1 + COUNT(*)
    FROM sampleData
    WHERE (date_due < t.date_due OR (date_due = t.date_due AND id < t.id)) AND
        order_id = t.order_id
) AS instalment_num,
    t.date_due
FROM sampleData t
ORDER BY t.order_id, t.date_due
```

This query will order the `instalment_num` by `due_date` in ascending order.  And in the case of a tie in `due_date`, it will order by the `id` in ascending order.

**Follow the link below for a demo:**

## SQLFiddle

Comment: I was going to write the same answer, but it will run into problems if a duplicate order_id/date_due appears.

Comment: Thanks. Does this take into account the fallback to ordering by ID, if the `date_due` is the same for two rows in the same `order_id` grouping?

Comment: @jarlh Would ordering the records in a subquery give order by `id` in the event of a tie in timestamps?  The documentation appears to say that MySQL will honor the order (although MariaDB does not).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, I have no idea at all. (I have never used MySQL.)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I am using MySQL so MariaDB in this particular case is of no relevance.

Comment: I will attempt a Fiddle.

Comment: If the ID will be ordered automatically, is it safe enough to assume the second sub query is not needed?

Comment: @BadHorsie I am not certain that there would be an automatic order, as most RDBMS do not have any internal order per se.

Comment: Interesting. And how would I perform that as an UPDATE?

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
  sub.order_id, sub.date_due,
  @group_rn:= case 
              when @group_order_id=sub.order_id then @group_rn:=@group_rn:+1 
              else 1 
              end as instalment_num,
  @group_order_id:=sub.order_id
FROM (select @group_rn:=0, group_order_id=0) init, 
     (select * 
      from the_table
      order by order_id, date_due) sub
```